# Are there other large margin classifiers than SVMs?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

When reading about SVMs (e.g. on the German Wikipedia) there is a sentence like "an svm is a large-margin classifier).

Are there other large margin classifiers than SVMs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one famous example are boosting techniques like [Adaboost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost). It uses small classifiers to create a big one.

Here you can find more info about [margin classifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_classifier).